# Function in VBA does not work in excel

Tags: excel, vba, function

So I am trying to write a function that takes two arguments (strings) and adds them together.

If I try to call this function using subroutine as you can see in the code below, everything works and a message box with the two strings shows.

However, when I go to excel spreadsheet and enter the function into a cell like this: `=add_strings("doesnt", "work")` or `=add_strings(doesnt, work)`, it doesnt work and displays value error instead.

However, when I define a function with only single argument - then it works. So if I put one string as the function argument and the define another string inside of the function and then return the strings appended, it works. But when I have more arguments, excel kind of struggles to accept them. Any ideas? thank you

```
Function add_strings(a As String, b As String) As String
add_strings = a & b
End Function

Sub caller()
Dim strVar As String
strVar = add_strings("doesnt", "work")
MsgBox strVar
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have a "return" or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of vba ;) In vba you return by assigning a value to a variable with the same name as the function. So `add_strings = a & b` is actually the return statement of the function.

Comment: What is your locale? Possibly the parameter separator on your system is not `,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the function in excel 2013 and it works fine without any errors

Check the attached screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0WHW.png

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - the parameter separator indeed wasn´t a comma but a semi colon (;).